# How could I read config in ipython notebook?

Tags: configuration, jupyter-notebook

I'm using anaconda 2.1 distributive.
I had created my own config section

```
from IPython.config.configurable import Configurable
from IPython.utils.traitlets import Int, Float, Unicode, Bool

class Myconfig(Configurable):
    token = ""
```

Then initialization

```
c = get_config()
load_subconfig('Myconfig.py')
c.Myconfig.token='Somethingusefull'
```

How could I read Myconfig.token in notebook?

Thanks!